# IPv6 link-local address in /etc/hosts

Tags: ipv6, hosts

I have an entry like this in `/etc/hosts`:

```
fe80::XXXX:XXff:feXX:XXXX%enp0s25 test-ipv6
```

This is a link-local address.  I've masked out my MAC address (with the 7th most significant bit flipped) for this post.

I can ping the address, but pinging `test-ipv6` gives

```
ping: test-ipv6: Name or service not known
```

- Why doesn't it work?
- Is there a different way to assign an IPv6 link-local address to a hostname?

I'm using Arch Linux with kernel version 4.17.2.

**EDIT:** this is mostly a duplicate of [IPv6 scope ID in /etc/hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174767/ipv6-zone-id-in-etc-hosts).

Comment: you probably instead want to use a not link-local address as whatever reads `hosts` doubtless does not know about what interface the address is supposed to be on

Comment: @thrig Yes, with a link-local address you always have to specify the interface (in my example this is `%enp0s25`).

Comment: Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174767/ipv6-zone-id-in-etc-hosts. TL;DR: It's not supported by the lookup routines, and seems to be a long-standing issue. My guess is that `ping` special-cases literal link-local addresses.

Comment: @ErikF That question is basically asking for the same thing as my question (although I'll leave my question to make it easier to find for people with my problem).
Note that the special case for link-local addresses is in Linux' network stack, as ping shouldn't even try to resolve them if someone gives IP addresses to ping (independent of whether they are link-local or not).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IPv6 scope ID in /etc/hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174767/ipv6-scope-id-in-etc-hosts)

Answer (score 0):

Use Link-local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR) or Multicast DNS (mDNS) (implemented by `systemd-resolved`) on your network. With LLMNR or mDNS, the hosts on the local network respond with their own hostnames. On a modern Linux distribution, the scope id for a link-local IPv6 address is returned by the resolver and everything should work even when using link-local IPv6 addresses.

Depending on your Linux distribution, you may already have LLMNR enabled: try

```
ping -6 somehost
```

(or `ping6`) where `somehost` is the host on the same LAN you are trying to reach.